# Creating a DLL, confusion with __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

```
Visual Studio C++ 2005
Windows XP
```

I am creating this DLL library. The DLL actually links with another LIB. I have included the headers and lib path. Everything compiles ok.

Actually, this code I wrote for running on linux, which runs ok. Now I am porting it to run on windows.

However, I have noticed that some DLL from some code samples use this in there header file:

```
static __declspec(dllexport) float some_function(int num1, int num2);
```

However, I have done the following, sample code below for the header *.h file. However, not sure if I still need the above or not?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

media_t* get_media(media_description_t* obj);
void* get_item(media_description_list_t *obj, int num);
int get_number_format(media_t *obj);
const char* get_media_value(media_t *obj);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Sample code for for implementation *.cpp file

```
int get_number_format(media_t *obj)
{
    Media *med = (Media*)obj;
    return med->getNumFormat();
}
```

So, do I need this `static __declspec(dllexport)`?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: If it links successfully, you obviously don't need it.

Comment: Sorry, this DLL links with another lib, and calls the the functions of that lib. I haven't created the application that will like with this DLL yet. I just wanted to get some information first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linker needs to be told which of your functions should be exported, making them usable by other code that uses your DLL.  __declspec(dllexport) does this.  But you can also do it by providing the linker with a .def file, a list of exported function names.  Somewhat painful because it now is up to you to keep that file in sync with your code.  Docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`__declspec(dllexport)` adds the function to the DLL's export table. This table is a convention that allows a process wishing to use the DLL to correctly call the function.

There are other ways to [export functions from DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8%28VS.80%29.aspx), but this one is probably the more modern and easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is needed, if you don't have the dllexport the function will not be accessible in any other application where you are calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the implementation of a method in the h file, you don't need to use the `__declspec(dllexport)` declaration.